# Three.js hidden elements when zoom

Tags: javascript, graph, three.js

Some links tend to not be displayed depending on the camera position.

The problem is visible on [this demo](http://anvaka.github.io/ngraph/examples/three.js/Basic/index.html?graph=grid3&z=1) when you zoom in a lot (like in the picture).
[image: missing_links]
Have you any idea to solved it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your camera near plane is at 0.1 but the far plane value is very large. Try lowering it.

Comment: Thx for advice, but it doesn't help. With low far plane no change except if I zoom out, links are not visible more quickly. Links that disappear are usually those with nodes ends out of the camera.

Comment: as suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184061/mesh-suddenly-disappears-in-three-js-clipping there is an `Object3D` property called `frustumCulled`. Try setting it to false.

Comment: That's great with this. Thx gaitat !